Expo SDK 51 breaks npm install
I migrated to SDK51, resulting in the npm install process breaking in the EAS build during the installation phase. Seems like @expo/webpack-config and expo have depency issues.
my package.json:
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.5.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.9.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^18.9.3",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.7.5",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.2.1",
    "axios": "^1.6.5",
    "bad-words": "^3.0.4",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^3.3.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "expo": "^51.0.8",
    "expo-app-loading": "^2.1.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.14",
    "expo-device": "~6.0.2",
    "expo-image-picker": "~15.0.5",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.28.3",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "firebase": "^10.7.1",
    "google-auth-library": "^9.4.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.1",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.12.0",
    "react-native-charts-wrapper": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-numeric-input": "^1.9.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.8.0",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.27",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-svg": "15.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10",
    "react-router-native": "^6.21.1",
    "request": "^2.88.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.5",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.24.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^5.4.3",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^12.4.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "detox": "^20.18.1",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^27.6.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^4.1.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-expo": "~51.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.2"
  },

Running npm install results in the following error:
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm error
npm error While resolving: @expo/webpack-config@19.0.1
npm error Found: expo@51.0.8
npm error node_modules/expo
npm error   expo@"^51.0.8" from the root project
npm error   peer expo@"*" from expo-splash-screen@0.17.5
npm error   node_modules/expo-app-loading/node_modules/expo-splash-screen
npm error     expo-splash-screen@"~0.17.0" from expo-app-loading@2.1.1
npm error     node_modules/expo-app-loading
npm error       expo-app-loading@"^2.1.1" from the root project
npm error   18 more (expo-application, expo-asset, expo-constants, ...)
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer expo@"^49.0.7 || ^50.0.0-0" from @expo/webpack-config@19.0.1
npm error node_modules/@expo/webpack-config
npm error   @expo/webpack-config@"^19.0.1" from the root project
npm error
npm error Conflicting peer dependency: expo@50.0.18
npm error node_modules/expo
npm error   peer expo@"^49.0.7 || ^50.0.0-0" from @expo/webpack-config@19.0.1
npm error   node_modules/@expo/webpack-config
npm error     @expo/webpack-config@"^19.0.1" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

I have tried deleting node_modules and doing npm install in my local development enviroment, the problem is repeated there aswell now.
I am expecting the npm install to work so that my expo go and EAS build works

Had this same issue and spent hours trying to resolve it. All you need to do is to remove @expo/webpack-config from package.json. eas build should work after that. I assume you have metro installed already (replaces webpack). See package.json and check you have @expo/metro-config or similar there and your good to go after removing @expo/webpack-config line from the file.

Yes you are correct, the webpack is deprecated in the newest  Expo versions:

Source

